# Доступ к удаленной базе на Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Работаю над программой с возможностью доступа к базе данных. Насколько я понял - mysql не подходит для работы с базой на Xamarin. Выбрал sqlite. Протестировал CRUD на локальной базе - работает. Хотелось бы перейти к работе на удаленной базе. Вот отрывок кода для операции CREATE.

```
        public void CreateTreasure(int innerID, string desc, int siteID, int userID, SQLite.SQLiteConnection database)
    {
        string dbname = "treasures.db";//Название базы
        string databasePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), dbname);//Создание полного пути к базе
        database = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(databasePath);//Установка подключения с базой
        database.CreateTable<Treasures>();//Проверка присутствия таблицы
        Treasures item = new Treasures(innerID, desc, siteID, userID);//Создание объекта
        database.Insert(item);//Добавление объекта в базу
        Treasures.Add(item);//Добавление в кешированный массив, дабы не тратить время на синхронизацию с базой
    }
```

**Возможно ли работать с удаленной базой в SQLite**? Если нет, то **какие еще технологии взаимодействия существуют для работы с удаленной базой на Xamarin**?

UPD: Для базы данных планирую использовать интернет хостинг.

Comment: `mysql не подходит для работы с базой на Xamarin` o_O `работе на удаленной базе` не надо удалять базу :) Вам нужно приложение для работы с БД (например редактирование таблиц БД с мобильника), или БД для работы приложения? Если второе, то посмотрите, что такое FireBase.

Comment: Sqlite - однопользовательская СУБД, к ней нельзя одновременно обращаться из нескольких процессов/приложений. По этой причине у нее нет возможности удалённого доступа. Но при большом желании... https://stackoverflow.com/a/61717428/5045688

Comment: "Взрослые" СУБД можно настроить для удалённого доступа. В частности, MySql: [Set up a remote MySQL database connection](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/mysql_remote.html)

Comment: Ваша удаленная база где будет расположена? В локальной сети или в глобальной? Если последнее, то лучше сделать нормальный сервер с WebAPI.

Comment: @aepot БД нужно как раз для нормального функционирования приложения. Подключаемся к базе на Android и вносим изменения/читаем содержимое. В долгосрочной перспективе постараюсь разобраться с FireBase, но хотелось бы что-то, что может работать с тем, с чем я умею работать сейчас. Спасибо за совет.

Comment: `для нормального функционирования приложения` прямой доступ к базе - это нарушение безопасности. Сколько у вас будет пользователей приложении? И каждому вы дадите пароль от базы? Первый попавшийся грамотный юзер зайдет к вам в базу напрямую и удалит все данные. Или изменит все пароли, или еще что-то сломает. Вам нужен либо нормальный сервис типа того же FireBase, либо свой сервер.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov на то база и удаленная, что не локальная. Не думаю что разработка API поможет мне решить проблему подключения из приложения, так как использовать компьютер в роли сервера не планировал - собираюсь использовать Web-хостинг. Суть в том, что я не знаю средств, которые могут мне позволить использовать строку подключения или IP/URL, по которым можно было осуществить подключение.

Comment: `собираюсь использовать Web-хостинг` Web API прекрасно может работать на веб-хостинге. Так как по сути Web API  - это тоже своего рода сайт, только не для людей, а для приложений.

Comment: Сеть локальная - вы понимаете? - сеть! Не БД локальная, а сеть. Есть глобальная сеть - Интернет. А есть локальные сети - интранет. Например, сеть вашей организации, или домашняя сеть, или домовая. В локалке, чисто теоретически, можно выставить кишки БД наружу, выдав строгие права пользователям.

Comment: `Не думаю что разработка API поможет мне решить проблему подключения из приложения` всем помогает, а вам возможно и не поможет. В любом случае, я подсказал про всё что мог. Доступ к базе из сети = взлом базы злоумышленником. Ни один нормальный сервис не дает доступа из сети к базе. База доступна только локально серверу, а сервер уже работает с внешним миром.

Comment: @aepot Пока для приложения не планируется массовость пользователей: думаю, до 10. Поэтому ищу любую возможность реализации. Бэкап данных уже предусмотрел.

Comment: Толку от бэкапов, если я приду в вашу базу и украду все пароли пользователей, в том числе и ваш? Потом данные поломаю вам. Буду повторять эту процедуру раз в неделю, пока вам не надоест восстанавливать бэкапы. Да и при чем тут бэкапы, если вы хотите открыть дверь в базу всем желающим?

Comment: @aepot Понял. Значит без постороннего софта работа с не-локальной базой невозможна? Просто надеялся что есть такие же средства как Entity Framework для .NET.  Если так, то буду разбираться с FireBase'ом. Спасибо что просветили.

Comment: Entity Framework - это как раз штука для удобного доступа к базе, используемая в серварах, а не клиентских приложениях.

Comment: _без постороннего софта работа с не-локальной базой невозможна_ - с чего вы взяли? Вы читаете через одно предложение? Откройте ссылку по настройке мускуля, которую я дал выше. Просто нужно выставить БД наружу. Всё! И можно работать с ней хоть через Entity Framework. Просто это небезопасно и не рекомендуется.

Comment: @aepot `Entity Framework - это как раз штука для удобного доступа к базе, используемая в серварах, а не клиентских приложениях` можете пояснить, я это не понял?